# HI.I have an error with findViewById

Tags: java, findviewbyid

```
public class HomeFragment extends BasePageFragment {
    private Unbinder unbinder;


//    @BindView(R.id.fab)
//    FloatingActionButton mFab;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);


    ImageButton ImageButton = (ImageButton) FindViewById (R.id.imageButton);
    ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mowmo.minimale");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is your error? Is it a compiler error or runtime error?

Comment: All lot of error here. Read the compiling error to understand them. (Statement after return, `FindViewById` not found, not sure the compiler will see the difference between `ImageButton` and `ImageButton`)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts here:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);
```

None of the code following this statement will ever execute since you've already returned the inflated View. Change it to this:

```
View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);


ImageButton ImageButton = (ImageButton) rootview.findViewById (R.id.imageButton);
ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mowmo.minimale");
          startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    });

return rootview;
```

This inflates the view and allows you to access the child views on the inflated view (using the findViewById method) before returning the view.